# C# and thread-safety of a bool

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am very confused about this subject - whether reading/toggling a bool value is thread-safe.

```
    // case one, nothing
    private bool v1;
    public bool V1 { get { return v1; } set { v1 = value; } }

    // case two, with Interlocked on set
    private int v2;
    public int V2 { get { return v2; } set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref v2, value); } }

    // case three, with lock on set
    private object fieldLock = new object();
    private bool v3;
    public bool V3 { get { return v3; } set { lock (fieldLock) v3 = value; } }
```

Are all of them thread-safe?

**EDIT**

From what I have read ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433772/are-primitive-data-types-in-c-sharp-atomic-thread-safe)) atomicity of bool does not guarantee it will be thread safe. Will then `volatile` type help?

Comment: None of these are thread-safe.  The thread that calls the getter will always read a stale value.  How stale it is depends on the processor and the optimizer.  Ranges from a handful of nanoseconds to infinity.  The getter needs to synchronize as well.  Or you'd use ManualResetEvent/Slim.

Comment: @Ksv3n *Assignement is always an atomic operation* False, `long` (64 bit) assignment by a 32 bit program isn't atomic.

Comment: @HansPassant A getter can read an old value, this is understandable. However, how could it last to infinity? Using a lock will make it read the *correct* value - reread it as if it was volatile? I don't think it works that way, I am confused about what you're saying. I thought that once nobody is writing anymore, the getter will work correctly.

Comment: It will be infinity when the optimizer stores the backing variable in a processor register and doesn't reload it from memory.  Because it doesn't know that another thread can update it.  The x86 jitter does that if the bool isn't declared volatile.  Example [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/458193/17034).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, not all of them are thread safe.

Case one isn't actually completely thread safe, or better saying - it isn't thread safe at all. Even if operations with boolean are atomic, variable value can be stored in a cache, and so, as in multicore CPU each core has it's own cache, value can be potentially corrupted.

Going even further, compiler and CPU can perform some internal optimizations, including instruction reordering, which can harmfully affect your program's logic.

You can add the `volatile` keyword, to notify the compiler that this field is used in a multi-threaded context. It will fix problems with cache and instruction reordering, but doesn't give you truly "thread safe" code (as write operations still will be not synchronized). Also `volatile` cannot be applied to local variable.

So when dealing with multi-threading you always have to use some technique of thread synchronization on valuable resources.

For more information - read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154803/2152334) answer, which has some deeper explanation of different techniques. (example there is about `int`, but is doesn't really matter, it describes general approach.)

Comment: *value can be potentially corrupted* No, value can't be corrupted (as in "transform in illegal/undefined value"). You could get stale ("old") values.

Comment: I mean "corrupted" in a way "not one, that it should be or you expect it to be". Definitely not a corrupted in a sense of memory corruption:)

Comment: "as in multicore CPU each core has it's own cache, value can be potentially corrupted." -- this might be a misunderstanding? I've heard hardware caches on modern x86 CPUs are always consistent.

Answer (score 42):

A little bit late but should be useful to the others.

You can implement your own thread safe boolean in the following way:

```
// default is false, set 1 for true.
private int _threadSafeBoolBackValue = 0;

public bool ThreadSafeBool
{
    get { return (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeBoolBackValue, 1, 1) == 1); }
    set
    {
        if (value) Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeBoolBackValue, 1, 0);
        else Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadSafeBoolBackValue, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Be sure to use Property everywhere, never access `int` variable directly.

Comment: In the `get` why not use [`Interlocked.Read(ref _threadSafeBoolBackValue) == 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.read?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) instead of `Interlocked.CompareExchange`?

Comment: Simple, because where is no Interlocked.Read for `int` parameter. If you really want to use `Interlocked.Read` method, you may change back value type to `long`.

Comment: If I were to make `_threadSafeBoolBackValue` and `ThreadSafeBool` static for a class that is static, would thread safety will still valid?

Comment: @Justin Yes, it will. `Interlocked` methods didn't distinguish static and instance variables, and static initialization is thread safe. So, I see no problems in this case.

Comment: I just started using .Add(ref _threadSafeBoolBackValue, 0) == 1

Comment: @user1664043 seems valid as well, good catch. Btw, the `set` method could also be simplified as `Interlocked.Exchange(ref _threadSafeBoolBackValue, value ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 10):

Nope, it isn't. But the solution is quite easy.
To make a bool (or anything, actually) thread safe, it's easy to use [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock) statement like this:

```
object locker = new object();
protected bool _somebool;
public bool Somebool
{
    get
    {
        lock (locker)
            return _somebool;
    }
    set
    {
        lock (locker)
            _somebool = value;
    }
}
```

Now you may enjoy your thread safe of `<T>`.

Comment: this is thread safe but the order of execution is not guaranteed. Assume multiple threads want to write, the order of acquiring the lock may be different than the order of actually getting the lock. So you set true, false, true with three threads and the outcome may be true, true, false with a final value of false.

Comment: @user2290269 I have actually never tested that - never needed to. if you need thread-safe objects then you are making multi-thread operations which means their execution/finish order is also not guaranteed so actually I can't quite get the point.