# How to check if another thread is within a locked section, using AsyncEx?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, asynchronous, nito.asyncex

I've just started using [Nito.AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) package and `AsyncLock` instead of a normal `lock() { ... }` section where I have `async` calls within the locked section (since you can't use `lock()` in such cases for [good reasons](https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/) I've just read about). This is within a job that I'm running from Hangfire. Let's call this the 'worker' thread.

In another thread, from an ASP.NET controller, I'd like to check if there's a thread that's currently executing within the locked section. If there's no thread in the locked section then I'll schedule a background job via Hangfire. If there's already a thread in the locked section then I don't want to schedule another one. (Yes, this might sound a little weird, but that's another story).

Is there a way to check this using the `Nito.AsyncEx` objects, or should I just set a flag at the start of the locked section and unset it at the end?

e.g. I'd like to this:

```
public async Task DoAJobInTheBackground(string queueName, int someParam)
{ 
    // do other stuff...

    // Ensure I'm the only job in this section
    using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
    {           
        await _aService.CallSomethingAsync());           
    }

    // do other stuff...
}
```

and from a service called by a controller use my imaginary method `IsSomeoneInThereNow()`:

```
public void ScheduleAJobUnlessOneIsRunning(string queueName, int someParam)
{ 

    if (!_asyncLock.IsSomeoneInThereNow())
    {
        _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<MyJob>(x => 
            x.DoAJobInTheBackground(queueName, someParam));
    }

}
```

but so far I can only see how to do this with a separate variable (imagining `_isAnybodyInHere` is a [thread-safe bool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233660/8479) or I used `Interlocked` instead):

```
public async Task DoAJobInTheBackground(string queueName, int someParam)
{ 
    // do other stuff...

    // Ensure I'm the only job in this section
    using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
    {
        try
        {
            _isAnybodyInHere = true; 
            await _aService.CallSomethingAsync());
        }
        finally
        {
            _isAnybodyInHere = false; 
        }
    }

    // do other stuff...
}
```

and from a service called by a controller:

```
public void ScheduleAJobUnlessOneIsRunning(string queueName, int someParam)
{ 

    if (!_isAnybodyInHere)
    {
        _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<MyJob>(x => 
            x.DoAJobInTheBackground(queueName, someParam));
    }

}
```

Really it feels like there should be a better way. The `AsyncLock` [doc says](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncLock.md):

> You can call Lock or LockAsync with an [already-cancelled CancellationToken](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/Cancellation.md)
> to attempt to acquire the AsyncLock immediately
> without actually entering the wait queue.

but I don't understand how to do that, at least using the synchronous `Lock` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how to do that

You can create a new `CancellationToken` and pass `true` to create one that is already canceled:

```
using (_asyncLock.Lock(new CancellationToken(canceled: true)))
{
  ...
}
```

The call to `Lock` will throw if the lock is already held.

That said, I don't think this is a good solution to your problem. There's always the possibility that the background job is just about to finish, the controller checks the lock and determines it's held, and then the background job releases the lock. In that case, the controller will not trigger a background job.

Comment: Ah, it throws an Exception. Now I understand, thanks! Yes, I agree it's a bad solution. I just can't fix all the problems in one release :)

Answer (score 0):

You must ***never(!)*** make any assumptions about any *other* thread or process!

What you must instead do, in this particular example, is to "schedule another job," unless you have already done so. *(To avoid "fork bombs.")*  Then, the job, once it actually begins executing, must decide: *"Should I be doing this?"* If not, the job quietly exits.

Or – perhaps the actual question here is: *"Has somebody else already* ≤scheduled_this_job≥?"

Comment: Yeah, I agree, that restructure just entails more changes than I can do right now ... maybe... But you're absolutely right.