# How to determine CancellationTokenSource scope?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, cancellationtokensource

Instead of using conventional threading, I am using `async/await` to implement a long-running job that will be called from various scenarios such as Desktop/Web/Mobile.

This question is about design considerations when using `CancellationTokenSource/CancellationToken` objects. Consider the following code written in .NET Core 5:

```
System
System.Collections.Generic
System.Diagnostics
System.IO
System.Threading
System.Threading.Tasks

[STAThread]
private static async Task Main ()
{
    using (var job = new Job())
    //using (var source = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        job.OnJobProgress += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine (watch.Elapsed); };

        Task.Run (async () => await job.StartAsync());
        //Task.Run (async () => await job.StartAsync (source.Token));

        do
        {
            await Task.Delay (100);
            if ((Console.KeyAvailable) && (Console.ReadKey ().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
            {
                //source.Cancel();
                await job.CancelAsync();
                break;
            }
        }
        while (job.Running);
    }
}

public class Job : IDisposable
{
    public EventHandler OnJobProgress;

    private bool _Running = false;
    private readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
    private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public bool Running => this._Running;

    public async Task StartAsync () => await this.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    public async Task StartAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await this.ProcessAsync(cancellationToken);

    public void Cancel ()
    {
        this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        do { Thread.Sleep (10); } while (this._Running);
    }

    public async Task CancelAsync ()
    {
        this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        do { await Task.Delay (10); } while (this._Running);
    }

    private async Task ProcessAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        lock (this.SyncRoot)
        {
            if (this._Running) { return; }
            else { this._Running = true; }
        }

        do
        {
            await Task.Delay (100);
            this.OnJobProgress?.Invoke (this, new EventArgs());
        }
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);

        lock (this.SyncRoot)
        {
            this._Running = false;
            this.CancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
            this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose () => this.Cancel();
}
```

Notice the three commented lines in the `Main` method as well as the `Cancel` and `CancelAsync` methods. My gut says that there should be a locking mechanism in place in the `Cancel` methods instead of the `Process` method. Depending on where the `CancellationToken` comes from, are there any potential deadlocks in this implementation? Somehow, I am not comfortable with the `do/while` blocking mechanism.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**AUXILIARY QUESTION:** Since `CancellationToken` is a `readonly struct` and being passed around `by value`, how is it that calling `Cancel` on the `CancellationTokenSource` modifies the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` property? Perhaps that was the source of confusion all along.

Comment: `Somehow, I am not comfortable with the do/while blocking mechanism` - so don't use it? Simply `await` your `Task.Run(...)` in `Main`, and then have an unrelated key press handler that flags the cancellation token?

Comment: Your gut feeling is correct. This combination of a `bool` flag and a loop that observes this flag is inefficient, introduces latency, and it's most certainly buggy. A thread is not supposed to read a non-[`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) variable that is mutated by another thread, without synchronization. The changed value may not be visible by the current thread. You can take a look at this: [C# and thread-safety of a bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411961/c-sharp-and-thread-safety-of-a-bool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for [Task.WhenAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=WhenAny%20%28Task%2C%20Task%29%201%20Parameters.%20The%20first%20task,any%20of%20the%20supplied%20tasks%20has%20completed.%20). Await the first job to complete from two: either the one you want to really want to complete or the one representing user's impatience by hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key or appropriate mobile touch.

Pseudocode:

- `mainTask = Setup main task, take the token as input`. That's it.
- `userInterruptTask = Setup user action monitoring task`, and in it's continuation or as part of its natural loop's time to end (the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key), call [Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel?view=net-5.0). Note, in this loop, there is NO check against a boolean value; it just goes until it must cancel, and then is done via break/return; the other task goes to done if it is properly listening for cancellation.
- So, when either task completes, you're done.

```
var ret = await Task.WhenAny(mainTask, userInterruptTask);
```

If it matters at this point, get the value of `ret` and act accordingly. Task.WhenAny [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-5.0#:%7E:text=WhenAny%20%28Task%2C%20Task%29%201%20Parameters.%20The%20first%20task,any%20of%20the%20supplied%20tasks%20has%20completed.%20)

> A task that represents the completion of one of the supplied tasks. The return task's Result is the task that completed.

For a specific answer to "what is the scope" of the token... its scope is *everything that may act on it*. Cancellation in TPL is 100% cooperative, so all tasks that care to set cancellation or look for cancellation are in play.

For your auxiliary question, I can understand your confusion. I hadn't thought of it before, myself, but the answer turns out to be simple. The implementation of that property delegates to the token source:

```
public bool IsCancellationRequested 
    => _source != null && _source.IsCancellationRequested;
```

where the [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-5.0) is a stateful class.