# Is a C# static method's variable initialised every time the method is called?

Tags: c#, static-methods

In the example below, will a new StringBuilder(255) be created every time the static Flog.Log() function is called, or will it only be created the first time the method is called?

```
public class Flog {

    public static void Log(FlogType flogType, string msg, params System.Object[] p) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(255);
        sb.Length = 0;
        sb.AppendFormat(msg, p);
        Log(flogType, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

I realise I could work around this with a static member variable.

Edit: The purpose of the question is one of optimisation - in some languages initialisation of the StringBuilder sb variable will only occur once.

Comment: everytime, since the method is static, not the variables, and they will run out of scope and be flagged for garbage collection

Comment: I don't think this deserves to be closed, as this question relates more to compiler optimization IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will a new StringBuilder(255) be created every time the static
>   Flog.Log() function is called, or will it only be created the first
>   time the method is called?

It will be created every time the static method called `Log` is called.

Only `static` members of a class are created once. So if `sb` would have been a static field of the class, the the `StringBuilder` would have been created only once.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224050/are-variables-in-static-methods-are-also-static-in-c)

> C# does not support static local variables (variables that are declared in method scope).